# How to handle/catch error with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

```js
function abc() {
  try {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('inside timeout!!');
      throw new Error('Somehting went wrong!!');
    }, 1000);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Gonna catch it here and throw is again', err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
try {
  abc();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err caught here', err);
}
```

How to catch the error ? Where should I wrap my code with try/catch ? 
Even with promise why catch block didn't catch the error.

```
async function abc() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     throw new Error();
   }, 1000);
}

try {
  abc();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err is ', err);
}
```

Comment: You have to wrap the inside of the callback, since `setTimeout(() => {throw new Error();}, 1000);` is a successful call. The error doesn’t come until later.

Comment: You should reject the promise in order for catch function to execute. This catch function is different from the `try catch` construct to catch exceptions

Comment: @Xufox, that means no way to catch errors of any callback function outside of the callback function ?

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it into a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```js
function abc(simulateError) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (simulateError)
        reject('Something went wrong')
      else
        resolve('foo')
    })
  })
}

// Call it using then/catch to handle result or errors...
abc(true).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})

// or await on the Promise, which allows using try/catch.
;(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await abc(true)
    console.log(result)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})()
```

Comment: Any other suggestion instead of .catch block with promise.

Comment: Yes, [error-first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) but that's an outdated practice.

Comment: What's the difference between .catch of promise block and normal catch block

Comment: `try/catch` won't help you here, even if it's within an `async` function. The only way to handle errors from `setTimeout` is either by passing a callback or Promises.

Comment: With Async and await, have to await just for the catch block only, isn't it the limitation of normal catch block ?

Comment: `try/catch` won't work properly for asynchronous code unless you're `await`ing something inside the `try` block.

Comment: ` async function abc() {
         try {
              await setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('inside timeout!!');
              throw new Error('Somehting went wrong!!');
           }, 1000);
        } catch (err) {
              console.log('Gonna catch it here and throw is again', err);
              throw new Error(err);
        }
       }

       (async () => {
            try {
                await abc();
                console.log('after timeout');
            } catch (err) {
               console.log('err caught here', err);
          }
      })();`

Comment: Not sure I can help you, the code you posted indicates you don't really undestand how asynchronous code works to begin with. For one, setTimeout doesn't return a `Promise` so you can't await it. Also throwing errors from within `setTimeout` won't help you in any case, either `async` or non-`async` functions. `setTimeout` uses a *callback* to propagate it's result. You can either wrap it into a `Promise` and use `reject` or use callbacks to propagate the error. Throwing errors won't work (unless you overwrite `setTimeout` as an `async` function and use it as such but that's another story).

Comment: Thank you so much! One more things, by passing async function to setTimeout function, how can i await it?

Comment: You cannot `await setTimeout` because `setTimeout` does not return a `Promise`.

Comment: So it does not make any sense to pass async function as a first argument of the setTimeout Function, as you mentioned no way to await it. Plz correct it if i am wrong.

Comment: You are correct